# data is not getting retrieved through SOAP API webservice after application upgraded to oracle 11g

Tags: java, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, oracle11g, oracle10g

we have upgraded our asp.net application code to oracle client 11g by just adding oracle.dataaccess.client references. we have an interface with another application which is java based, for them to retrieve data from our application database. they are using our webservice url to send their inputs and to send their credentials.They are using SOAP API,WSDL methods to send the information. But after we upgraded oracle client 11g version,they are able to send inputs to our end and the procedure in the backend is getting invoked correctly. But they are unable to get the output to their end. showing 'array out of bound exception' error on their end. But when we revert oracle client changes to the old oracle 10g version, everything works fine. Can anyone help me to understand this scenario?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are using the right jdbc driver.  I think it should be ojdbc6.jar